# Replace all values in a list with np.nan

Tags: python, numpy

How to replace all values within a list with np.nan?

`a = [1.58, 2.13, 3.98, 4.12]`

and what i want is

`a = [nan, nan, nan, nan]`

I have tried many options like `replace` or list comprehension, but it didn't work.

Comment: Is it important to you to change the values in the list itself, or can it be a new list that will be assigned as a new reference into `a`? A new list is easy, `a = [np.nan for v in a]`. If you want to change the list itself, then an obvious solution will be a for loop with assignments: `for i in range(len(a)): a[i] = np.nan`

Comment: Note that if `a` was a numpy array rather than a list, then you could have done `a[:] = np.nan`.

Comment: Actually, if you want to apply the changes on the list itself, you can do this: `a[:] = [np.nan] * len(a)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
a = [1,2,3,4]
a = [np.nan]*len(a)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[nan, nan, nan, nan]
```

Answer (score 3):

A numpy way of doing it natively:

```py
a = np.full(shape=4, fill_value=np.nan).tolist()
```

Scales well to higher dimensions and larger size.

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.full_like(a, np.nan).tolist()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to update the existing list `a` then you can do this:

```
a[:] = [np.nan] * len(a)
```

or even more efficiently - using a generator, rather than constructing a new list just for the assignment:

```
a[:] = (np.nan for v in a)
```

But if you don't mind throwing `a` away and replacing it with a whole new list, then you can just do:

```
a = [np.nan] * len(a)
```